# qemu: boot from cdrom

Tags: qemu, xubuntu, kernel-panic, root-filesystem

I'm trying to install `xubuntu` on a usb flash drive following [this quide](https://askubuntu.com/a/17018/186999). The command I'm running is

```
qemu-system-x86_64 -drive file=/dev/sdc,media=disk,index=0,format=raw -cdrom ./xubuntu-15.10-desktop-amd64.iso -boot menu=on
```

`/dev/sdc` is my usb drive formatted as `ext4`. It starts to boot from `xubuntu*.iso`, as I can see this screen

[image]

But then I get kernel panic

[image]

I was able to boot this image with `virtualbox`, though. Which partition is it tring to mount? This must have nothing to do with `/dev/sdc`, or not? What am I doing wrong? Any clues?

Comment: the guide says not to format your destination `/dev/sdc` usb disc as the installed will try to avoid accidentally overwriting an existing system.

Comment: @meuh, what exactly do you suggest? I don't have Disk Utility. Should I do `dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sdc bs=... count=...`?

Comment: I think that is worth a try (I dont have or know what the Disk Utility does either).

Comment: I ran `dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sdc iflag=nocache oflag=direct bs=4096` before starting `qemu`, but nothing changed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems this obscure error is due to the ramdisk of the kernel image having grown so much these days that it no longer fits in the default size for ram memory of the qemu virtual machine (which is quite low at 128 MiB).  Simply add a memory option like:

```
-m 512M
```